# Function in echo why does it bugs?

Tags: php, sql, function, echo

I read some topics here and in other forums and find a way to set a function in a echo.
But it doesnt show my stuff.
My Code

```
echo "<tr>
        <td>
           Choose people:<br>
            ",choose_kunde(),"
        </td>
    </tr>";
```

my function:

```
   function choose_kunde()
{
    require './config/config.inc.php';
    if($result2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT kunden_id, vname, nname FROM kunden"))
    {
        echo "<select name='kunde_a'>";
        while($adr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$adr['vname']."|".$adr['nname']."|".$adr['kunden_id']."'>".$adr['vname']." ".$adr['nname']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Daten konnten nicht aus der Datenbank gelesen werden.<br>";
        echo mysqli_error($db);
    }
}
```

Comment: As in, you're getting a white page? Or it's not displaying in order?

Comment: Guessing the problem here is that the output of `choose_kunde` is output *before* the rest of the `echo`. Either 1) `return` the final string from your function instead of `echo`ing it, or 2) finish your `echo`s separately: `echo "..."; choose_kunde(); echo "...";`.

Comment: Before i found the way to use echo ",function()," i got a white page. now it shows alls but not the select in the function.
@decezeit doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your function to return string instead of echoing it.

example:

```
function choose_kunde()
{
    $output = '';
    require './config/config.inc.php';

    if($result2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT kunden_id, vname, nname FROM kunden"))
    {
        $output .= "<select name='kunde_a'>";

        while($adr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {
            $output .= "<option value='".$adr['vname']."|".$adr['nname']."|".$adr['kunden_id']."'>".$adr['vname']." ".$adr['nname']."</option>";
        }

        $output .= "</select>";
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= "Daten konnten nicht aus der Datenbank gelesen werden.<br>";    
        $output .= mysqli_error($db);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

and then concatenate it

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>
       Choose people:<br>
        " . choose_kunde() ."
    </td>
</tr>";
```

Still you need work on the code to make it more clean.

Comment: You can still do `echo .., choose_kunde(), ..`, and I'd recommend that over concatenation (it's ever so slightly more performant).

Comment: to conccatenate it with . its shows me a white page.
with , it shows me my table etc but still dont work

Comment: yes @deceze he can do it but i prefer returning value over using echos inside functions but it's matter of taste. About your white page check the logs use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see what the error is.

Comment: Its a bit embarrassing.. i had a wrong include path to the functions.php that is why it doesnt works -.- hate these types of bugs I am searching many minutes/hours for the bug and its just a wrong path.. But @Robert ur code works finde thank you :)

Comment: @Robert That's not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about your *second* code block.

Comment: @xKushGene This would have been very easy to fix had you activated error reporting and/or looked at your error logs. Further, use `require` instead of `include` to get much more visible errors for such situations. **Learn to love error reporting.**

Answer (score 0):

You have write your function with return system. Try with this code.

```
function choose_kunde()
{
    $html = '';
    require './config/config.inc.php';
    if($result2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT kunden_id, vname, nname FROM kunden"))
    {
        $html .= "<select name='kunde_a'>";
        while($adr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {
            $html .=  "<option value='".$adr['vname']."|".$adr['nname']."|".$adr['kunden_id']."'>".$adr['vname']." ".$adr['nname']."</option>";
        }
        $html .= "</select>";
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= "Daten konnten nicht aus der Datenbank gelesen werden.<br>";
        $html .= mysqli_error($db);
    }
  return $html;
}
```